# How to translate nmcli IP6.GATEWAY format to network-manager yaml file syntax?

Tags: networking, network-manager

What goes in the yaml file where I have placed these question marks?

```
gateway6: "????::?"
```

Continue reading for more detail.  OS =  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS   I am attempting to set a static IP via netplan, (aka network manager)  by means of editing the file `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

Performing `nmcli device show`  displays a line `IP.GATEWAY`  but it is 2 hyphens.  There is , however an `IP6.ROUTE[1]`  that dsiplays what can only be described as technical network gibberish.  How do I translate this output to a correct format inside of the yaml file?  I do not know what dst, nh, and mt are or what these deep secrets are supposed to mean.   What should by placed into where there are question marks?

```
$ more /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 

    # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: NetworkManager
      ethernets:
        enp0s8:
          dhcp4: no
          dhcp6: no
          addresses: [192.168.4.26/16,"fe80::6d70:90de:cb83:4491/64"]
          gateway4: 192.168.0.1
          gateway6: "????::?"
          nameservers:
           addresses: [192.160.248.16,192.160.248.21]
```

.
.

```
    $ nmcli device show enp0s8

    GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s8
    GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
    GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:00:27:81:16:20
    GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
    GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     ethernet-enp0s8
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
    WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
    IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.4.26/16
    IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
    IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 600
    IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
    IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.160.248.16
    IP4.DNS[2]:                             192.160.248.21
    IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          bcs.mit.edu
    IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::6d70:90de:cb83:4491/64
    IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
    IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
```

Comment: I'd make those entries in Network Manager directly and revert netplan to its default. https://tecadmin.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/setup-static-ipv4-address-in-ubuntu2204.png